# MEDIAN() window function on stable Maria DB

Tags: sql, mariadb, median

I need to perform a MEDIAN calculation as part of a query. My developer told me this is possible with Maria DB 10.3.3 but my server admin told me they can upgrade only to 10.3.2 since that is the latest stable release. I see 10.3.3 was released on 23 Dec 2017, how is it still just a beta?

Anyway, what will be my best options to use some kind of MEDIAN functionality? Making sub-queries will be both ugly, slow and consume more CPU.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  For a numeric value:

```
select avg(col)
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum in ( cnt / 2, (cnt + 1) / 2, (cnt + 2) / 2);
```

For a string or date, it is harder to use interpolation, so I would simply recommend:

```
select col
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum in ( cnt / 2, (cnt + 1) / 2);
```

Comment: is that a way to calculate MEDIAN on Maria DB 10.2? if so, how does it differ from the actual window median offered on 10.3.3?

Comment: @user8411456 . . . These calculate the median.  The first interpolates, which is the "mathematical" definition of median.  The second chooses an arbitrary value if there are ties (which can happen with an even number of rows).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the latest stable release from [MariaDB downloads page](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/+releases/) (currently 10.4.11). Using native `median()`-function will be faster than calculating it yourself.